Discontinuous solution of $y''(x)-2(1-x)(y'(x))^2=0$ with $y(0)=1$ and $y(2)=-1$
I tried to solve the equation $$y''(x)-2(1-x)(y'(x))^2=0$$ with the conditions $$y(0)=1, y(2)=-1.$$
It's easy to verify that the function
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
satisfies both the equation and the conditions.
The problem is the function is discontinuous at $x=1$ while what I know -May be wrong- is the solution of differential equation is always continuous!. So I tried to solve it using Mathematica and here is the result

which is a perfect continuous solution.
Does the problem have more than one solution? Is the discontinuous solution wrong? Is Mathematica wrong? Did I miss something?
Edit:
I worked the problem manually by the method of separation and obtained two distinct solutions:
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
and
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}-1}}tan^{-1}(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}-1}})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}-1}}tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}-1}})+1$$
where
$$c=-2.2767175312280725973119838$$
The question now is:
Why should I consider the discontinuous function to be NOT solution of the differential equation??

One quickly finds that $$y''(x)-2(1-x)(y'(x))^2=0\iff y'(x)=\frac1{(x-1)^2+C}.$$
Now, for the solution to be defined at $x=1$, and satisfy $y(2)<y(0)$, $C$ must be negative.
Your candidate $y(x)=\frac1{1-x}$ corresponds to $C=0$.

@AnneBauval I don't disagree. But my question is why should I consider the discontinuous function NOT solution?

$x\mapsto\frac1{1-x}$ is not "discontinuous". It is undefined at $x=1$. A solution of an ODE with initial conditions $y(x_k)=y_k$ deserves this name only if it is defined on some interval containing the $x_k$'s.

Maybe see it this way: If you allow points where the solution is not defined and you consider the trivial ODE $y'(x)=0$, then $y:\mathbb{R}\setminus {0} \to \mathbb{R}$, $y(x)=-1$ $(x<0)$ and  $y(x)=1$ $(x>0)$ would be a solution. You can define this to be a solution, but nobody does, and most theorems on solutions would fail.

@Gerd what if in a different problem we found the only function that satisfy the problem is discontinuous. Should we consider it as a solution or consider the problem to be unsolvable?

@MohamedMostafa For the case of ordinary differential equations I would consider it as unsolvable.

Mohamed, this is another question, since (I think you agree now) $\frac1{1-x}$ was not "discontinuous" at $1$ but undefined. If a candidate is really discontinuous then it cannot be a solution, since a solution must be differentiable (by definition). The only thing you can do, if your candidate $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ is, say, solution on $[a,b)$ but discontinuous at $b$, is to restrict $f$ to $[a,b)$. This restriction will be a solution on that interval.

Solutions of equations always depend on the solution concept you choose, that is, you first have to define what you mean by a solution. However, your problem is a classical Dirichlet boundary value problem and in this context I've never seen anyone calling a function with a singularity in the interior of the interval a solution. Boundary value problems can in fact be unsolvable or have multiple solutions. In your case you can try to solve the ODE $v'-2(1-x)v^2=0$ by the method of separation of the variables and then integrate $v$ to obtain general solutions of $y''-2(1-x)(y')^2=0$. If I have done this right, the general solution should be
$$
y(x)=\frac{1}{2c}\log(\frac{c+1-x}{c+x-1}) +d
$$
with constant $c,d$. Inserting the boundary value condition gives $d=0$ and $c$ has to be chosen such that
$$
\frac{1}{2c}\log(\frac{c+1}{c-1})=1.
$$
Numerically this equation has a solution $c \approx 1.1997$, hence $c>1$, so that the solution above is defined and differentiable on $[0,2]$.
At least the graph of this function is near your output of Mathematica.

I think there is a missing negative sign in the numerator which corresponds to c=0.

@MohamedMostafa I am not sure what you mean. I doublechecked the general solution with maxima and it satisfies the ODE. $c=0$ is not admissible.
